# [Wso2][Stream Processor][Dashbord] Running dashbord and worker in same machine

Tags: wso2, worker, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I try to run Worker and dashbord in same machine.
the first tools is running coorectly, but when i start the second the error has been raised :

> [2018-03-07 09:59:43,546]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.websocket.EndpointsRegistryImpl} - Endpoint
>   Registered : /server-stats/{type}
>       [2018-03-07 09:59:43,636]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.data.provider.DataProviderAPI} - Data Provider
>   Service Component is activated
>       [2018-03-07 09:59:44,909]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.websocket.WebSocketServerSC} - All required
>   capabilities are available of WebSocket service component is
>   available.
>       [2018-03-07 09:59:45,049]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MicroservicesServerSC} - All microservices
>   are available
>       [2018-03-07 09:59:45,346]  INFO {org.wso2.transport.http.netty.listener.ServerConnectorBootstrap$HTTPServerConnector}
>   - HTTP(S) Interface starting on host 0.0.0.0 and port 9643
>       [2018-03-07 09:59:45,939]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.core.config.model.JmxReporterConfig} -
>   Creating JMX reporter for Metrics with domain
>   'org.wso2.carbon.metrics'
>       [2018-03-07 09:59:45,954]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.core.reporter.impl.AbstractReporter} -
>   Started JMX reporter for Metrics
>       [2018-03-07 09:59:45,954]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.analytics.metrics.MetricsComponent} - Metrics
>   Component is activated
>       [2018-03-07 09:59:45,970]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.internal.DataAgentDS} - Successfully
>   deployed Agent Server 
>       [2018-03-07 09:59:52,914] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager}
>   - Runtime Exception occurred while calling onAllRequiredCapabilitiesAvailable of component
>   carbon-datasource-service
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during
>   pool initialization: Connection is broken:
>   "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out:
>   169.254.235.125:59336" [90067-196]
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.initializeConnections(HikariPool.java:581)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:152)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.(HikariDataSource.java:73)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.rdbms.hikari.HikariRDBMSDataSource.getDataSource(HikariRDBMSDataSource.java:56)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.rdbms.hikari.HikariDataSourceReader.createDataSource(HikariDataSourceReader.java:74)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.DataSourceBuilder.buildDataSourceObject(DataSourceBuilder.java:79)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.DataSourceBuilder.buildDataSourceObject(DataSourceBuilder.java:60)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.DataSourceBuilder.buildCarbonDataSource(DataSourceBuilder.java:44)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.DataSourceManager.initDataSources(DataSourceManager.java:153)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.internal.DataSourceListenerComponent.onAllRequiredCapabilitiesAvailable(DataSourceListenerComponent.java:125)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.lambda$notifySatisfiableComponents$7(StartupComponentManager.java:266)
>         at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.notifySatisfiableComponents(StartupComponentManager.java:252)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver$1.run(StartupOrderResolver.java:204)
>         at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
>         at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
>       Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out:
>   169.254.235.125:59336" [90067-196]
>         at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
>         at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
>         at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:457)
>         at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:367)
>         at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.(JdbcConnection.java:116)
>         at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.(JdbcConnection.java:100)
>         at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.addConnection(HikariPool.java:496)
>         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.initializeConnections(HikariPool.java:565)
>         ... 15 more
>       Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>         at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>         at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createSocket(NetUtils.java:103)
>         at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createSocket(NetUtils.java:83)
>         at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:115)
>         at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:453)
>         ... 23 more
>
> can you please advise?
>
> Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Can you share the WSO2 SP version you were using when you got this exception?

Also please check whether the `AUTO_SERVER=TRUE`
 config is avaiable in the jdbc url of WSO2_METRICS_DB datasource configuration, which can be found in
**{WSO2_SP_HOME}/conf/worker/deployment.yaml**

eg : 
`jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:h2:${sys:carbon.home}/wso2/dashboard/database/metrics;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE'`

Comment: i used last release of WSO2 SP 4.1.0, and i already try with AUTO_SERVER=TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

I configured all datasource in mysql, and i can running all SP componnent.
the issue is related to H2 datasase, that not allowed to share connection with default configuration.

i will check default H2 connection parametrs, and test again.